# Copy Postgres table while maintaining primary key autoincrement

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy a table with this postgres command however the primary key autoincrement feature does not copy over. Is there any quick and simple way to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS TABLE table;
```

Comment: No such command exists in PostgreSQL. What's the *exact text* of the command that you are using? And what PostgreSQL version / release are you using? Some kind of variant like EnterpriseDB's Postgres Plus? The closest Pg equivalent is to use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` followed by a `COPY` and any required `setval` statements to set sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up creating the table with the same schema/settings and then copying all of the values over into the new table.

Comment: Replace `COPY` in my above comment with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` if you want to avoid a temp file. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: That's what I did but it turns out it doesn't update the autoincrement key. When I attempted to insert more rows into the duplicate table, I got an error saying that I can't have duplicate primary keys since it attempted to increment starting at 1.

Comment: Yes, you have to `BEGIN; LOCK TABLE thetable; SELECT setval('the_seq_name', (SELECT max(id) FROM thetable)+1); COMMIT;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE oldtable; 
CREATE TABLE newtable (LIKE oldtable INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
SELECT setval('the_seq_name', (SELECT max(id) FROM oldtable)+1);
COMMIT;
```

... though this is a moderately unusual thing to need to do and I'd be interested in what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm building tools to compensate for PostgreSQL's inability to not be wildly convoluted, instead of restoring the database directory via copy-paste if a building a tool fails I can use my table duplication tool to quickly replicate an existing table and retry the execution of another PostgreSQL tool very quickly. I *could* use the console but then I'd have to construct the query every time (sans up key), GUI is superior for getting things done quickly when a GUI is built competently. Thanks for sharing your answer.

Comment: this worked for me. I dumped my old table to CSV and then used the `\copy ....` command to load the CSV from my local to an RDS instance. I included the original id of the rows when i did the copy but the new table's sequence counter was starting at 0